# Hotkey to closing applications

Tags: release-juno

i'm rookie in Linux.

I need hotkey to close the applications. Ctrl+W doesn't always work.

Thank you.

Comment: Be specific. If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer. [How do I ask a good question?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to close any application by pressing `Alt+F4`